# How to use arithmetic operators in apache drill query where clause?

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to query a parquet file using Apache Drill. I want to sort the values and get the largest value of `FloatCol1`. So the following query works.

```
select * from dfs.tmp.`tmp.parquet` order by FloatCol1 desc limit 1;
```

I also have another column `FloatCol2` and I want to sort again using the ratio of `FloatCol1/FloatCol2`. So I did the following queries to try which will work but NONE did.

```
select * from dfs.tmp.`tmp.parquet` order by (FloatCol1/FloatCol2) desc limit 1;
select * from dfs.tmp.`tmp.parquet` order by (FloatCol1/FloatCol2) as ratio desc limit 1;
select * from dfs.tmp.`tmp.parquet` order by FloatCol1/FloatCol2 desc limit 1;
```

Can this kind of query be done? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now. I just have to make it like this

```
select * from dfs.tmp.`tmp.parquet` order by cast(FloatCol1 as decimal(28, 2))/cast(FloatCol2 as decimal(28, 2)) desc limit 1;
```

I have to cast each individual value before applying the operator.